# python run another time will kill kernel

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode, Listener

def on_press(key):
    if str(key) == r"<48>":# ctrl 0
        print("ctrl 0 exit")
        return False  
    elif str(key) == r"<51>":# ctrl 3
        print("ctrl 3 choose price")
        #pyautogui.confirm(text='choose',title='price',buttons=(1,2,3,4,5))
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

当运行listener时候，第一次按ctrl 3不会报错，但是当我按ctrl 0退出listener后，再运行listener然后按ctrl 3会挂掉内核？

listener运行按ctrl 0结束，然后重新运行按ctrl 3 不会挂掉内核

Comment: Did you have a question?